# Alexa device discovery not working - can you see what's wrong with this json?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I can't get device discovery working.  My discovery response is below.  Alexa keeps saying that it can't find any new devices.  Can you help?

This is data passed from my local server to the skill in lambda written in python then passed back to Alexa.

```
    {
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "messageId": "810212af-b373-4a23-a976-67c5d79324e4",
            "name": "Discover.Response",
            "namespace": "Alexa.Discovery",
            "payloadVersion": "3"
        },
        "payload": {
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "capabilities": [
                        {
                            "interface": "Alexa.ContactSensor",
                            "properties": {
                                "proactivelyReported": true,
                                "retrievable": false,
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "detectionState"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "version": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "interface": "Alexa.EndpointHealth",
                            "properties": {
                                "proactivelyReported": true,
                                "retrievable": false,
                                "supported": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "connectivity"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "type": "AlexaInterface",
                            "version": "3"
                        }
                    ],
                    "displayCategories": [
                        "CONTACT_SENSOR"
                    ],
                    "endpointID": "523F5AA2-079A-4A9A-94E2-EA4259357F80",
                    "friendlyName": "HumiditySensor",
                    "manufacturerName": "THCGuard AirNode",
                    "description": "AirNode output rule"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`endpointID` should be `endpointId` (lower case 'd')